# What does template.data._id do in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor

Beginner Meteor/JS question:

When associating objects in Meteor I see small line of code that I'm not understanding. For example, post with associated comments.

```
var $body = $(e.target).find('[name=body]');
var comment = {
  body: $body.val(),
  postId: template.data._id
};
```

So get the content of the comment, put it in the variable "comment", and also create a postId to go into this comment so you know what post the comment belongs to. This postId is being called in with *'template.data._id'*

My questions are:

1. So you call template, then wouldn't you want to call the template name? Not data? Where is data coming from?
2. That aside, so you call data...and then ._id, are there other options to 'data'? IE

   > template.data.(option)
3. This isn't working for me, haha, *console.log(template.data._id);* is coming back undefined. So it's not grabbing the object ID as advertised. I'm sure I messed something up.

Here's the surrounding code if you need more context:
https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/blob/master/client/views/comments/comment_submit.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beginning with the easiest first, under your point 3 it should read:

```
console.log(template.data._id);
```

As to points 1 and 2, the key idea to note is that your code is being called inside of Template.commentSubmit.events({}).  Inside of this object (the "{}"), you are working with an instance of the template in the document, including whatever data is being passed to that instance.  In a different template, you will receive different data and hence template.data will consist of different keys and values.  You can check out more in the documentation here, http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst.

So in answer to your question, the reason you can invoke "data" rather than the template name is that the template name has already been provided by Template.commentSubmit.  Note that inside of events({}), "this" will generally be equivalent to "template.data."  So

```
console.log(template.data._id);
```

will generally be equivalent to

```
console.log(this._id);
```

The properties you can access on the data will always vary based on the instance received by the template.  For example, if template.data consists of {_id: 1, name: "x", location: "y"}, you can retrieve these values by calling the keys, e.g. "template.data.name" or "template.data._id" etc.  In your example, you are correct that you are setting postID to template.data._id.

The data arriving to the template comes from your Meteor.subscriptions.  Hope this helps.

Comment: So you say the template is an object. What about when you have the nested templates? IE, a post template, then you call the comment template inside it. template.data._id is trying to get the parent template ID but it sits within the child template. Does the parent Id always override the children? Or is that based on routes?

Comment: There is no direct way to traverse through parent templates inside of Template.name.events({}), so the data will be the "child" data.  But you can change the data context of the template using the handlebars {{#with }} command. For example, if you have <template name="post> {{> comment}} </template>, Template.comment.events() will not be aware of post. But <template name="post"> {{#with ../this}} {{> comment}} {{/with}} </template> makes the data context for comment the parent post.  Not sure if this is exactly how your case is set up, but it should provide one pattern for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The template has a data context. When you use an `{{#each}}` block you are iterating through data, in this case posts.

So using `template.data` retrieves the data context for the template. It would refer to a post from where the comment form is. So `template.data._id` is the equivalent of this `post._id` (where post is the post you're commenting on).

The thing is I think this was removed from meteor. It was there a couple of versions back. I'm not sure about this but that's what I thought. I would have thought the correct code should be `this._id`. Where `this` ends up being the data context of the form (which would again be the post).

Could you check if that gives you `undefined` if you changed it out?

Comment: Thanks Tarang, I did try this._id and I got the same undefined I believe. I'm going to try it again tonight and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Yup, it just says undefined..Idk what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The .events method of a template takes in an event map:

http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps

The callbacks for each of the events (in this case 'submit form') can take two arguments. The first one 'e' is the javascript event object and the second one 'template' is the instance of the template where the event occurred. That template instance has a bunch of utility methods/properties (see http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst) one of which is .data (see http://docs.meteor.com/#template_data). That .data property returns the data that the template was bound to (in your Microscope example it looks like it's bound to a comment object) and that object (in this case) has an _id property.

Note that the 'template' (little T) is not the same as Template (big T).